# Python Multithreaded Video Read/Write

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I've been trying to optimize a vision processing application I have that reads from a USB camera, processes the frame, then writes the frame to a file. I've seen examples where people handle this by threading the video read/write and the processing just takes the last frame and deals with it in parallel. I will only be able to process a frame once every second or so.

I have been playing around with some simple code examples but wondering if there is a well tested and used library that does this somewhere? I don't think my examples are industrial strength and I also have times when my environment just freezes when the app completes.

Comment: You should show us what you have tried.  The key is good communication between the threads.  You can use a `Queue` for this; have the capture thread store one frame per second on the `Queue`, and have the processing thread block waiting for something to appear.

Comment: so you have to discard frames, right?

Answer (score -1):

It's easy as py! Here's a basic template for working on an image in a separate thread. All you have to do is replace implementation of `f()` to your desired concurrent functionality:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import cv2

def f(image):
    print(cv2.sumElems(image))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
    while True:
        _, image = cap.read()
        exe.submit(f, image)
```